# HTML Characters within the jWysiwyg Editor

Tags: jquery, html-entities, jwysiwyg

I am lost on what this issue may be. I am using jQuery long with the plug-in called jWysiwyg.

Whenever I enter an HTML Entity Name or Number `&copy;` or `&#169;` within the editor it reverts to the actual character. There is no function for this, which I assume it must be character setting.

I have no problem with this on some characters – but not all of them, as few of them are coming as square boxes or the black diamond on the actually web page when posted.

I tried changing the character sets everywhere possible and this is not solving my issue.

As anyone else come across this and have a work around to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Its because WYSIWYG editors render html entities such as &copy; to their character value (the copyright symbol), just in the same way  would display as an image in a WYSIWYG editor. I had a similar issue with a different jQuery based editor.

I assume the only way you can fix that is to convert it back to a html entity when you submit it, or probably less likely to work properly, string replace & with `&amp;` on every html entity when you load the editor. That way it would show up as &copy instead of the copyright symbol, which should(?) make it store as &copy instead of the © symbol...

Perhaps [this will help](https://github.com/alecgorge/jwysiwyg/commit/75572925497bdd957ff920a2016cad8f3703b62a)? It's a utility function made for jwysiwyg meant to post things as their html entity code. Though that idea of using `<code>` tags dynamically would probably work well too :P, and you'd just use a strip_tags on the server.

Comment: I would give this a try first.

Comment: This works - expect just a little to well. It converts everything as in the opening and closing brackets on hrefs, paragraphs, etc. Will try the other example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a funny little way, you answered your own question.

When I first loaded this page, I noticed © and I was confused about what you were trying to do.  Then, you edited it, and © became `&#169;` If you view source, you'll see that when you hit the "code block" button in the editor on StackOverflow, the copy symbol showed up the way you wanted it to.

This was done by wrapping it in the [code element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp) in the html (you can right click > view source to see...

```
<p>Whenever I enter an HTML Entity Name or Number <code>&amp;copy;</code> or <code>&amp;#169;</code> within the editor it reverts to the actual character. There is no function for this, which I assume it must be character setting.</p>
```

I've never used the editor you're referencing; but it looks like they just use default javascript events.  So to accomplish your goal, you probably have to add an event to your editor, and then onKeyUp, you search the text for the special characters and wrap them in code.  So, pseudo code would be something like (I didn't test this so it might be a little buggy)...

```
  $("textarea").wysiwyg({
    keyup: function(event) {

      var editorContent = getContent();  // Or whatever you call to get the content

      // Replace all instances of $# followed by 3 digits and a semicolon, with
      // the same thing, only wrapped in a code block.
      editorContent.replace(/&#[\d]{3};/g, <code>&#[\d]{3};<\\code>); 

      // Again, I don't know if this function exists, just throwing it out
      // there so you get the general idea.
      setEditorContent(editorContent);
    }
  });
```

As I said, I didn't give this a try; so edit your answer with what you ended up using if it works for you.

Comment: I tried this method, which does wrap the code element. I also did manually when text was copied and pasted. In theory I see where you are going with this. Unfortunately still changes. `<code>&#169;</code>` switches to `<code>©</code>` Which leads me to believe there must be a bug within the editor itself. I found other editors that do not have issue or have no special plugins to allow it to work.

Comment: Only other thing I can say is that this may not be a bug; it could be XSS filters built into the editor. Even though anybody attempting an XSS attack through your text editor is likely to know how to sidestep any client side filters; I wouldn't be surprised if they still exist in the editor you're using for good measure.  If you aren't already familiar with XSS attacks then you should google it and read up - especially if you're working on a public facing site.

Comment: I have it secure from attacks so I am ok on that end. As for this whole scenario HTML Entities, I decide to just go this route. [link](http://ethilien.net/websoft/wordcleaner/cleaner.htm), here is the scripting was using and rather then using the equivalent to what he suggests, I will change them to the actual HTML Character that works with the editor and the web sites.